# Caniuse is not accurate. When did Firefox begin supporting localStorage?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I know that it works in FF 14.

However when I went to look at caniuse.com it showed FF 18+

http://caniuse.com/#search=localStorage

When did support actually begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Since version 3.5.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#Browser_compatibility) but there may be more to that. It's possible the standard changed and the current version of localStorage, in its present form, wasn't supported till what caniuse says. I have not looked into that but a note on their page says the storage APIs used to be under HTML5 and, perhaps, that may have caused the category to change.

Comment: Actually, this is just a bug in caniuse.  When they moved categories on their site they didn't copy the historical data, just the then-current data....

Comment: Thanks @BorisZbarsky, I noticed that some time ago and was wondering about that. I almost said I hoped you would come here to clarify that...and there you are! :)

Comment: Well... I don't have any special knowledge about caniuse, but the above is at least my best guess.  ;)

Comment: @pure_code - Fyrd has a lot of stuff going on. I'm sure he's aware of the issue.